# How to sanitize html/javascript from request.JSON in grails 3.1.10 restful service

Tags: json, rest, grails

We have a grails 3.1.10 restful service that takes in json data on the http post. This data can contain html/javascript which is not desired.

Using encodeAsHTML and the xss-sanitizer plugin XssSanitizerUtil.stripXSS methods I can see how to sanitize an individual string, but how can I push this to a higher scope through filters or something so that when request.JSON is used in the controller it has already been sanitized?

Or is there already another easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an interceptor to apply to the appropriate controllers. In it I made a copy of the JSON parse(HttpServletRequest request) method. Near the end of the method where it parses the inputStream I plugged in my Sanitizer class that uses xss-sanitizer:

```
def body = IOUtils.toString(pushbackInputStream, encoding)
def sanitized = Sanitizer.sanitize(body)
json = JSON.parse(sanitized);
```